# What's wrong with do .. while loop in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, loops

I was experimenting with different kinds of loops in JS and came across a very weird behaviour.

The example from this [page](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/do...while) works just fine. But this code

```js
var N = 10
var i = N
do {
   console.log(i)
   if (i == N) i-=3
   else i+=2
} while (i < N)
```

prints 10, 7, 9, 11 instead of 10, 7, 9 as expected in both Chrome 45 and Firefox 47. That's really very weird. I converted this loop into C language and ran it with this online [tool](https://www.jdoodle.com/c-online-compiler), and it worked correctly. Why is the behavious in JS is different to C (and also not consistent)? It seems to me that in my scenario the interpreter saves variables' values in the beginning of each iteration and uses cached values in the end of the iteration instead of the actual ones. Is it really defined in standard this way?

By the way, if I run this code as a snippet using online JS interpreter, it works fine.

Comment: it is already giving 10 7 and 9 only

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oh, sorry, I got it. 11 is the return value of the entire code. Though I don't understand why is it exactly 11 and not the result of 11 < 10 (e.g. false) for example. Maybe it should be this way.